# Bootstrap limit carousel indicators but can still cycle

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to limit the carousel indicators to two (2) but as you can see in the code below, I have four (4) images to slide. When I slide to the 3rd image the carousel indicator does not cycle, obviously because there are only two indicators. How do I cycle the carousel indicators if this is the case?

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
   <!-- Carousel indicators -->
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
   </ol>   
   <!-- Carousel items -->
   <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
         <img src="/bootstrap/images/slide1.png" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="/bootstrap/images/slide2.png" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="/bootstrap/images/slide3.png" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="/bootstrap/images/slide4.png" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Carousel nav -->
   <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" 
      data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
   <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" 
      data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you find your answer ?

Answer (score 2):

*One way is*

**The doc** : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-usage

**The bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/9UP4lv26ih

**The Js** :

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e){
  $index = $('div.item.active').index()%2;  
  $carouselIndic = $('[data-slide-to="'+$index+'"]');
  $('.carousel-indicators li').removeClass('active');
    $carouselIndic.addClass('active');  
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work if I have a case of 5 slides with 2 indicators (just an example). When I slide to the 5th image (index 4), using your code: 4%2 is 0, and when I slide to the next image which is the 1st image, it is also at index 0. Therefore, using ordered pairs to illustrate:  (imageIndex,indicator) => (0,0),(1,1),(2,0),(3,1),**(4,0),(0,0)**,(1,1),(2,0)...

Props to your answer though, but I prefer it to continue to cycle between the two indicators, like this: (0,0),(1,1),(2,0),(3,1),(4,0),(0,1),(1,0),(2,1),... and so on. This should also work when I have cases like 3 indicators.